# Word VBA system.collections.queue Issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently trying to make a macro in VBA for word to go through a document and take each instance of a text format, and input it into a different line of a table. To do this I have a loop which cycles through each instance of this format, and adds it to a queue, and puts each item in the queue in a different cell in a table, however when I run the program I hit an error at

```
Imports System.Collection.Queue
```

which says "Compile Error: Method or data member not found" and it won't let me use the queue elements of the program. The rest of the program all works fine. I assume this is because VBA cannot access the System.Collection.Queue library. Is there away I can access the queue functions in VBA or a different way I should implement this program without using a queue?

Comment: `Imports` is not part of VBA...

Comment: You can try using `CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")`  Note it's Collection*s* with an s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim q
Set q = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")

q.enqueue "A"
q.enqueue "B"
q.enqueue "C"

Debug.Print q.peek '>> "A"

Do While q.Count > 0
    Debug.Print q.dequeue
Loop
```

Comment: This works, and allows me to create the queue, but I'm having issues adding the selected text to the queue. So I go through and find the text in the document using Selection.Find and then select the text, how would I then add it to the queue?

Comment: Sorry, it was working, I was just pasting the selected text on top of the selected text so it disappeared. Thanks for the help!